# Mirror indents in MS Word and wrong position of ruler handles

Tags: microsoft-word, indentation, right-to-left, ruler

I created a document with mirror margins for book layout and also mirror indents to place a note box along text in each page. Options are as follows:

> Word Options > Advanced > **Document view = Left to Right**
>
> Page Setup > Margins > **Multiple pages = Mirror margins**
>
> Margins > **Inside = 4 cm**
>
> Margins > **Outside = 2 cm**
>
> Margins > **Gutter = 0 cm**
>
> Page Setup > **Paper = A4**
>
> Page Setup > Layout > Section > **Section Direction = Left to right (Whole  document)**
>
> Page Setup > Layout > Headers and footers > **Different odd and even = checked**

Now on even pages handles of ruler are displayed on wrong position as you can see in the second screenshot.

On Odd pages ruler handles are on correct position:

[image: ruler on odd pages]

On even pages it's not correct:

[image: ruler on even pages]

This makes limitations to have a right to left paragraph among this left to right text.

Also for adding tab stops near outside margin I should go through Tabs dialogue and ruler is not functional to do it.

Is this a bug or I'm wrong somewhere?

You can download my sample document from [here](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8310051334/mirro_margin_mirror_indent.docx.html).

I tried this on Word 2013 and 2016, it behaves the same on both.

### UPDATE

For now as a workaround I removed mirror indents and increased the amount of outside margin.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem to be a bug, and you should report it to Microsoft.

However, it does not actually limit you, since you can always use "Format | Paragraph" to set indents and tabs in a dialog and with numeric values rather than visually on the rulers.

[image]

Comment: thank you. For Tabs yes, I can do it from dialog but I cannot solve the problem of right alignment with opposite text direction from there.